# How to show that $\sqrt{n}\leq\sqrt[n]{n!}$

Tags: induction

I'm having trouble proving the above formula.
I've tried taking the nth power of both sides, to get
$$n^{\frac{n}{2}}\leq n!\Rightarrow\underset{\frac{n}{2}}{\underbrace{n\cdot n\ldots\cdot n}}\leq1\cdot2\cdot3\ldots\cdot n=n\left(n-1\right)\left(n-2\right)\ldots\left(n-\left(n-1\right)\right)$$ But that's where I got stuck.
I've also tried induction, proved for $n=1,2$, and then I have trouble using the induction hypothesis, I can't find a way to plug it in when I have terms like $\sqrt{n+1},\sqrt[n+1]{\left(n+1\right)!}$
I would really appreciate a clue or a hint.

Comment: It doesn't hold for n=1, 2.

Answer (score 2):

Induction is not needed.

Both sides are positive, so we can take the $2n$-th power without changing the inequality.

You have to prove:

$$n^n<n!^2$$

Group factors of the RHS this way:

$$n!^2=(1\cdot n)\cdot[2\cdot(n-1)]\cdot[3\cdot(n-2)]\cdots(n\cdot 1)=\prod_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k)$$

So we have to prove

$$\prod_{k=1}^n n<\prod_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k)$$

It's not necessarily true, but it would be enough to prove that the inequality holds for all factors, i.e. $n<k(n+1-k)$, or equivalently $-k^2+(n+1)k-n>0$. The LHS of this inequality is a trinomial with roots at $k=1$ and $k=n$. Since the leading coefficient is negative, for all $k$ between $1$ and $n$, it's positive.

That is, $n<k(n+1-k)$ for all $k$ such that $1<k<n$, and $n=k(n+1-k)$ for $k=1$ and $k=n$.

Therefore $n^n<n!^2$ for all $n$ such that there is at least one number between $1$ and $n$, i.e. $n\ge3$. For $1\le n\le2$, the inequality is not strict: $n^n\le n!^2$ (it's actually an equality).

Comment: that was an excellent answer! Could you please share how you approached this problem when you first saw it?

Comment: @DS First, get rid of the roots. Then writing $n!^2$ as a product of factors in reversed order is an old trick to prove several inequalities on $n!$ (and it's said that Gauss used a [similar trick](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/384/did-gauss-find-the-formula-for-123-ldotsn-2n-1n-in-elementary-school) as a kid). So I have to humbly confess it was more of a reflex than actual reflection.

Comment: thank you for your insights :)

Answer (score -1):

What about to prove something more rude: $n! \ge \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n$.

Ones you prove this, it's will be easy to prove your statement.

Comment: Is it "more rude"? For $n=3$, the inequality of the question is $n!>3^{3/2}\simeq5.19$. Yours is $n!>1$.

Comment: "More rude" in terms of starting value of $n$ to prove initial inequality.